# jdbctemplate query() vs entityManager createQuery()

Tags: dao, entitymanager, jdbctemplate

What is essential difference between these methods?

**query()** of JdbcTemplate and **createQuery()** of EntityManager?

As I understand, both execute query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate.query()` executes a raw SQL query via Spring's JDBC API

`EntityManager.createQuery()` creates, but does not execute, a JPA query, via the native JPA API.

Same end result, very different mechanism.

Comment: thank you, i asked this question because it was strange for me ,when in Spring project was used EntityManager expression.